Backtrader not filling trailing orders properly
I believe backtrader does not properly fill trailing stops.
Please see sample code below that does the following (the data for the code is at the end of the question):

Enters a short position at 13:10
Adds a trailing buy order with trail amount being 0.19

class MyStrategy(bt.Strategy):    
    def __init__(self):
        # Keeps track if a trailing stop order already exists
        self.trailing_stop_order_exists = False    
        
    def next(self):
        # Sell at 13:10.
        if self.data.datetime.time() == datetime.time(13,9):
            self.order=self.sell(size=10)
        # Add a 0.19$ trailing stop     
        if self.trailing_stop_order_exists is False and self.position.size < 0:        
            self.order=self.buy(size=10, exectype=bt.Order.StopTrail, trailamount=0.19)
            self.trailing_stop_order_exists = True
     
            
cerebro = bt.Cerebro(stdstats=False)
data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=df)
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.broker.setcash(1000)
cerebro.addobserver(bt.observers.BuySell, barplot=True, bardist=0.0001)
cerebro.addstrategy(MyStrategy)
cerebro.addanalyzer(bt.analyzers.PyFolio, _name='pyfolio')
results = cerebro.run()
strat = results[0]
cerebro.plot(style='candle', volume=False, xaxis=True,candle_width=1,barupfill=False,bardownfill=False,barup='green')
pyfoliozer = strat.analyzers.getbyname('pyfolio')
returns, positions, transactions, gross_lev = pyfoliozer.get_pf_items()

Now if we look at the transactions from the strategy print(transactions) we can see that the strategy correctly entered the short position at 13:10 and then exited the position when the trailing order was hit at 14:19 with the execution price being 37.31.
Time of the transaction    Amount   Price
2024-03-21 13:10:00+00:00   -10     38.1388 
2024-03-21 14:19:00+00:00    10     37.3100 

The problem is that the execution price is not correct. It should be 37.28 instead of 37.31. If you look at the data below, the lowest price that was hit was 37.09 at 14:17, which means that if I add my trailing amount (0.19) to 37.09, I should get 37.28 execution price. My commission is 0 in the strategy.
Below is the data you will need for the code to run (put it in a pandas df with Datetime being the index)
Datetime            Open    High    Low     Close
2024-03-21 13:00    38.09   38.1    38.04   38.06
2024-03-21 13:01    38.06   38.1    38.05   38.05
2024-03-21 13:02    38.0599 38.0599 38.0032 38.0095
2024-03-21 13:03    38.0101 38.05   38.003  38.045
2024-03-21 13:04    38.04   38.055  38.02   38.055
2024-03-21 13:05    38.06   38.09   38.04   38.09
2024-03-21 13:06    38.1    38.19   38.1    38.18
2024-03-21 13:07    38.185  38.21   38.17   38.185
2024-03-21 13:08    38.18   38.19   38.1509 38.17
2024-03-21 13:09    38.16   38.165  38.134  38.1377
2024-03-21 13:10    38.1388 38.16   38.1198 38.1198
2024-03-21 13:11    38.1097 38.11   37.97   37.98
2024-03-21 13:12    37.99   38.0051 37.9728 37.975
2024-03-21 13:13    37.97   38.02   37.95   38.02
2024-03-21 13:14    38.02   38.03   38.01   38.02
2024-03-21 13:15    38.01   38.01   37.95   37.95
2024-03-21 13:16    37.96   37.985  37.96   37.965
2024-03-21 13:17    37.965  37.975  37.93   37.935
2024-03-21 13:18    37.935  37.9701 37.93   37.95
2024-03-21 13:19    37.955  37.96   37.9325 37.96
2024-03-21 13:20    37.96   37.96   37.92   37.9402
2024-03-21 13:21    37.95   37.99   37.95   37.98
2024-03-21 13:22    37.98   37.9845 37.9567 37.97
2024-03-21 13:23    37.96   37.96   37.925  37.9399
2024-03-21 13:24    37.935  37.9499 37.9203 37.945
2024-03-21 13:25    37.94   37.95   37.85   37.86
2024-03-21 13:26    37.86   37.86   37.76   37.77
2024-03-21 13:27    37.78   37.82   37.77   37.77
2024-03-21 13:28    37.775  37.82   37.77   37.795
2024-03-21 13:29    37.795  37.815  37.765  37.77
2024-03-21 13:30    37.76   37.76   37.6815 37.6963
2024-03-21 13:31    37.7    37.76   37.7    37.75
2024-03-21 13:32    37.76   37.825  37.76   37.825
2024-03-21 13:33    37.82   37.84   37.8065 37.825
2024-03-21 13:34    37.82   37.8299 37.77   37.79
2024-03-21 13:35    37.78   37.885  37.765  37.875
2024-03-21 13:36    37.88   37.88   37.82   37.85
2024-03-21 13:37    37.855  37.87   37.805  37.81
2024-03-21 13:38    37.81   37.81   37.71   37.725
2024-03-21 13:39    37.725  37.77   37.72   37.765
2024-03-21 13:40    37.765  37.765  37.68   37.695
2024-03-21 13:41    37.69   37.715  37.66   37.67
2024-03-21 13:42    37.67   37.715  37.67   37.7039
2024-03-21 13:43    37.694  37.6999 37.6501 37.6802
2024-03-21 13:44    37.6701 37.695  37.64   37.65
2024-03-21 13:45    37.645  37.645  37.555  37.59
2024-03-21 13:46    37.595  37.67   37.585  37.65
2024-03-21 13:47    37.64   37.655  37.6045 37.6045
2024-03-21 13:48    37.605  37.625  37.53   37.5433
2024-03-21 13:49    37.55   37.59   37.5203 37.54
2024-03-21 13:50    37.5481 37.62   37.545  37.57
2024-03-21 13:51    37.57   37.58   37.5301 37.56
2024-03-21 13:52    37.56   37.59   37.55   37.59
2024-03-21 13:53    37.58   37.58   37.545  37.575
2024-03-21 13:54    37.576  37.5777 37.525  37.53
2024-03-21 13:55    37.53   37.53   37.48   37.49
2024-03-21 13:56    37.48   37.4901 37.44   37.475
2024-03-21 13:57    37.48   37.525  37.4752 37.495
2024-03-21 13:58    37.5001 37.52   37.47   37.47
2024-03-21 13:59    37.46   37.49   37.45   37.47
2024-03-21 14:00    37.46   37.56   37.44   37.54
2024-03-21 14:01    37.535  37.5391 37.4978 37.5
2024-03-21 14:02    37.5044 37.515  37.42   37.44
2024-03-21 14:03    37.44   37.455  37.4    37.405
2024-03-21 14:04    37.4029 37.4497 37.39   37.44
2024-03-21 14:05    37.44   37.46   37.38   37.41
2024-03-21 14:06    37.4    37.41   37.365  37.38
2024-03-21 14:07    37.3767 37.38   37.34   37.345
2024-03-21 14:08    37.35   37.38   37.3403 37.355
2024-03-21 14:09    37.33   37.4497 37.3274 37.395
2024-03-21 14:10    37.39   37.4    37.34   37.35
2024-03-21 14:11    37.34   37.3898 37.26   37.27
2024-03-21 14:12    37.26   37.3201 37.255  37.29
2024-03-21 14:13    37.285  37.2879 37.215  37.25
2024-03-21 14:14    37.25   37.3    37.19   37.2001
2024-03-21 14:15    37.2001 37.2299 37.15   37.17
2024-03-21 14:16    37.15   37.16   37.11   37.12
2024-03-21 14:17    37.11   37.28   37.09   37.27
2024-03-21 14:18    37.28   37.3    37.18   37.2914
2024-03-21 14:19    37.29   37.3351 37.28   37.29

EDIT: Potentially correct solution.
The issue was that backtrader only uses the closing price (as opposed to correctly using High and Low of the candle) to update the trailing stop. To fix that, you need to go to: ...\backtrader\order.py and add two if statements:
    def execute(self, dt, size, price,
                closed, closedvalue, closedcomm,
                opened, openedvalue, openedcomm,
                margin, pnl,
                psize, pprice):

        ### ADD THE BELOW FOUR LINES 
        if self.issell():
            price = self.data.high[0]
        if self.isbuy():
            price = self.data.low[0]

        super(Order, self).execute(dt, size, price,
                                   closed, closedvalue, closedcomm,
                                   opened, openedvalue, openedcomm,
                                   margin, pnl, psize, pprice)


Please include a minimal reproducible code example in your post.

@py660 I revamped the question to make it reproducible
